# Python 3 list slicing raises an index error

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing

I've encountered a problem, which I guess is some sort of bug in either Python, my computer/windows, or both.

So far it hasn't been a problem to me and I haven't even known it's not supposed to happen.

When slicing a list out of it's index, value of `[]` should be returned:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l[5:]
[]
```

And this does indeed work on my mac and on my friend's computer as it's supposed to.

However, when I'm on my PC (Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit, Finnish), I get `IndexError: list index out of range`

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l[5:]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    l[5:]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I've got both Python 3.3.0 and 2.7.3, it works fine on 2.7.3 but the error raises on 3.3.0. I already tried reinstalling both versions, no effect. Python documentation also says it shouldn't raise an error on Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#IndexError

I can easily work my way around it with a simple `if len(l) >= 2`, but I'd rather not use something which should not be needed.

Didn't find much from google, was wondering if anyone else is encountering the same, and if there's a solution to this? Or should I perhaps contact the python developers?

Comment: You tested this is IDLE I suspect (`pyshell` is part of IDLE). Can you try in the normal python prompt (open CMD, run python 3.3 from the command line, try again).

Comment: I tried this in IDLE 2.7 and 3.3, and neither showed this behavior.  We'll need more clues as to exactly what environment Mahi is using.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Seems to work fine on cmd... Got `[]`, so the problem is within my IDLE?

Comment: @Mahi: looks like it, but others with IDLE on 3.3 on Windows have not reproduced your problem, so it's not just IDLE itself.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah I got `3.3` on my mac and it works just fine there, doing the exact same.

Comment: Can you provide the version details? like `Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`

Comment: @Kabie Got exactly the same as yours.

Comment: That's weird. Your CPU model? and language locale? Try `dis.dis('l=[1,2,3];l[5:]')`

Answer (score 0):

No. I'm unable to reproduce this error on a Win7 64bit Python 3.3.0 installation. In the command shell as well as in IDLE, the behaviour I see is exactly as expected.

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l[5:]
[]
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('l=[1,2,3];l[5:]')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (2)
              6 LOAD_CONST               2 (3)
              9 BUILD_LIST               3
             12 STORE_NAME               0 (l)
             15 LOAD_NAME                0 (l)
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (5)
             21 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             24 BUILD_SLICE              2
             27 BINARY_SUBSCR
             28 POP_TOP
             29 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
```

Please provide more details about any changes you might have made to your environment.

Comment: `pyshell` points to IDLE. It thus theoretically could be a bug in IDLE.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, thanks. Well, I get the exact same result in IDLE on my Python 3.3.0 64bit Win7 installation.